# AutoFixture: Mock implementation of multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have some code I want to test like

```
public class MyClass
{
  private InterfaceA _thing;
  MyClass(InterfaceA thing)
  {
     _thing = thing;
  }

  public MyType MyMethod()
  {
    if (_thing is InterfaceB bThing)
    {
      return bThing.MethodOnB();
    }
  }
}
```

In my test I want to be able to mock `_thing` as implementing both interfaces so that I can specify return values or verify the calls received by `MethodOnB` for the second interface, `InterfaceB`. Ideally I'd like to do this by having `thing` as a parameter to my test using a custom attribute as recommended by the [AutoFixture documentation](https://autofixture.io/articles/intro.html#injecting-test-data).

How can I create a mock that implements multiple interfaces with AutoFixture?

Comment: Which test framework are you using? Which mocking framework are you using?

Comment: Looks like a good feature request. ATM, AutoFixture is able to create simple `Substitute.For<T>()` mocks only: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/730b47884975d0c1256209073a719a9fe510d8a9/Src/AutoNSubstitute/NSubstituteMethodQuery.cs#L64

Comment: @DavidOsborne I'm using NUnit and NSubstitute. I have an answer posted creating the mock with NSubstitute directly. But I'm hoping I can have it mocked by "injecting" it as a a parameter to my test method.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but it doesn't take the mock as a parameter to the test method, which is the answer I'd like. But here it is with NSubstitute if anyone else just needs to get it working.

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
  // Arrange
  var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
  // Make a substitute with multiple interfaces using NSubstitute
  var thing = Substitute.For<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>();
  // Inject the substitute into AutoFixture so it can be injected when constructing our class.
  fixture.Inject(thing);
  var sut = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

  ((InterfaceB)thing).MethodOnB().Returns(...);

  // Act
  var result = sut.MyMethod();

  // Assert
  ((InterfaceB)thing).Received().MethodOnB();
}
```